# smallest natural $n>1$ such that $2^n>n^{1000}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Find the smallest natural number $n>1$ such that
$2^n > n^{1000} $ 

It seems with numeric methods that the correct answer is 13747.

But I'm still puzzled what is the correct rigorous analytical aproach to solve this particular problem and other similar problems?

Comment: $n = 0$ ;) If $0$ doesn't count as a natural number for some weird reason, $n = 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Great trick question!

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I forgot to mention that $n>1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to obtain the **bounds** of the least possible $n > 1$ such that $2^n > n^{1000}$, is to take $\log_2$ of both sides:

$$n\log_2{2}>1000\log_2{n}\\
n > 1000\log_2{n}$$

We let $n = 2^a$ for some positive integer $a$. Then
$$2^a > 1000a$$

Because $2^a$ grows a lot faster than $1000a$, it is a simple task to test values to find that the least value of $a$ is $14$. From this we see that the least valid $n$ is bounded by : $2^{13} < n_{\text{min}} \le 2^{14}$, or $8192 < n_{\text{min}} \le 16384$. Clearly, $13747$ conforms to this range.

As sas suggested, we can go on to improve this bound. Recall that $n > 1000\log_2{n}$, implying $\frac{n}{1000} > a$. If $n < 13000$, then $\frac{n}{1000} < 13$. Hence $n \ge 13000$. Similarly, if $n > 14000$, then $\frac{n}{1000} > 14$. From this we have a stronger bound for $n$ : $n \le 13000 \le 14000$.

Apart from calculating these bounds, I do not think that there is a way to actually compute by hand the smallest possible integer value of $n$, unless perhaps you want to do Newton-Rhapson's by hand.

Comment: You can also obtain, that $13000\leq n \leq14000$.

Comment: This realy seems to be a correct way to aproach that kind of problems. Finding the exact number by hand is not realy important.

Comment: @sas I would be really interested in how you would do that assuming you have no knowledge of the answer of $13737$ before hand.

Comment: @NikiPronko Thanks Niki! Do remember to mark either of the answers posted here as the solution (by clicking the tick beside it) if you find it useful and sufficient.

Comment: @YiyuanLee, you know that $2^{13}\leq n \leq 2^{14}$, so you know that $13\leq \log_2 n \leq 14$. So, for equality $\frac {n}{1000}=\log_2 n$ $n$ definitely must obey  $13000\leq n\leq 14000$.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the problem from an algebraic point of view, basically the question is to solve $$f(x)=2^x-x^{1000}=0$$ The solution of this problem is analytical in term of Lambert function and the solution is given by $$x=-\frac{1000}{\log (2)} W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{1000}\right)$$ which, numerically equals $13746.8$.

A quick check : $f(13746)=-5.923\times 10^{4137}$ and $f(13747)=2.029\times 10^{4137}$.

I really enjoy these small numbers (the mass of the universe is close to $10^{53}$ kg) !

So, the solution of the problem is $n=13747$.

**Added later**

For the considered branch of the Lambert function, an approximation is given by
$$W_{-1}(x)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{(L_2-2) L_2}{2 L_1^2}+\frac{(2 L_2^2-9L_2+6) L_2}{6 L_1^3}+ ...$$  with $L_1=\log (-x)$ and $L_2=\log (-\log (-x))$; for this specific case, this approximation leads to a value of $13746.4$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any analytical method for computing the exact value, since your problem is equivalent to $\dfrac{\ln n}n<\dfrac{\ln2}{10^3}$ , but the function $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln x}x$ does not possess an [inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) expressible in terms of elementary functions.